# UML - How to depict global functions in star uml?

Tags: c++, uml, staruml

I have a global function called ("UPDATE") that is static and only visible in the c++ file. However, it is still crucial to the classes function and I want to depict it in my staruml map.

I tried to do this by simply putting text in a rounded rectangle but I cant connect any arrows to this (I wish to demonstrate the use of the function using arrows etc).

*The exact reasoning for me not making this a static member is that I need it to be accessible to a thread* ***but not by the user instantiating the class.***

What is the "correct" way to depict such a function?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301526/uml-class-diagram-symbol-for-a-top-level-function

Comment: As mentioned above, this is simply not possible in UML. So I guess StarUML (if it's an UML tool) will also have no solution.

Comment: A suggestion, if the file maybe a dedicated namespace which could be modeled as a package, you can use a package visibility ~. That's could a solution to model you point, but if you need code generation also this is another story.